# String declared in header file of derived class is null in the super class

Tags: c++, string, inheritance, scope

So my header file looks something like this:

```
class DerivedClass : public BaseClass{
public:
    const std::string IMG_FILE_NAME = "picture.png";
};
```

and my cpp file looks like this:

```
#include "DerivedClass.h"

DerivedClass::DerivedClass(int x, int y) : BaseClass(x, y, IMG_FILE_NAME){
    //some code here.
}
```

In the base class I'm using the string(IMG_FILE_NAME) to open a file but for some reason it's null there, which breaks the program. Can someone explain what's going on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The base class will be constructed before the derived class. Because of this, `IMG_FILE_NAME` will not be instantiated in `DerivedClass` before it gets sent to the `BaseClass` constructor.

A possible workaround is to make `IMG_FILE_NAME` static. It should get initialized before the constructor is called.

Comment: Making it static would also ensure that there's only one instance of IMG_FILE_NAME. The way it is currently written, every instance of DerivedClass would have a copy of the string.